# Entity Framework Improperly tracking many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

### Setup

consider the following data tables:

```
*Files*
| PK_File_ID | Name |


*FileStatusLog*
| (Key) FK_File_ID | (Key) FK_Status_ID | (Key) Date |

*FileStatus*
| PK_Status_ID | Name |
```

The above table is represented by the following Code First objects:

```
public class File
{
    [Key]
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name {get;set}

    public virtual List<FileStatusLog>
}

public class FileStatusLog
{
    [Column(Order = 0), Key, ForeignKey("File")]
    public int Fk_File_Id { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 1), Key, ForeignKey("Status")]
    public int Fk_Status_Id { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 2), Key]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual File File { get; set; }
    public virtual FileStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public class FileStatus
{
    [Key]
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FileStatusLog> StatusEntries { get; set; }
}
```

### Problem

My problem arises when inserting a disconnected file.  I realize that this is the beloved task of inserting a disconnected Object Graph in Entity Framework, still a painful ordeal, but I have been able to do it before.  I suppose it is the Many-To-Many relationship that is throwing me off.

If I don't do anything to the file, and just Insert it, it tries to add a duplicate copy of `FileStatus`.  This is an expected Side Effect of inserting disconnected Object Graphs.  The Work around is to make sure that each `FileStatus` is mapped to the Data Context:

```
public File Insert(File FileToInsert)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < FileToInsert.FileStatusLog.Count; i++)
    {
        var Entry = context.Statuses.Find(FileToInsert.FileStatusLog[i].FileStatus.Id);
        if (Entry != null)
        {
            Entry = Mapper.Map(FileToInsert.FileStatusLog[i].FileStatus, Entry);
            FileStatusLog[i].FileStatus = Entry;
        }
    }
    context.Files.Add(FileToInsert);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The Problem is that the above code is not working as intended.  The Composite key table is only allowing 1 row per status. Whenever a new file is being inserted with a status that has been used before, that row in the `FileStatusLog` in being *overridden* by the new `File` Data.  How would I be getting this result?  Doing nothing, it tries to duplicate Statuses in the `FileStatus` table. Try to bind those Statuses, and it won't et you insert Duplicate `Status_Id`'s in the Join Table.

Any Ideas as to what is going on here?

Comment: Are the `FileStatusLog[i]` objects attached to the context? "*Overridden*" would mean that an UPDATE statement is written which, I believe, can only happen with attached (and then modified) entities.

Comment: That is my Understanding as well!  This question may need to just die out.  I can't really figure out why this was happening, but I just sort of switched a few things around and it started working as expected. There must have been something, somewhere that I was doing to bind those objects to the context.

Comment: @JHixson, if the join entity doesn't required the payload (`DateTime Date` in your case), you could just get rid of `FileStatusLog` and let the EF handle the non-PJT (pure join table) under the hood. Just a thought.. Join tables with payload (or relationship-with-payload) is trickier in any ORM (that of .NET, ROR et el), than many might have imagined. If you want to make it more interesting (perhaps for having a multi-selection for Files and Statuses in UI), try throwing a `ViewModel` for `FileStatusLog` to the mix. :)

Comment: I absolutely agree that this model makes it mroe difficult, but I do absolutely need that date.  Is tyhere a better way of tracking jthat information?  What I need from each file is to know at what time a file was put into what status.  A file could be put into any given status at any given time.  I'm absolutely open to suggestions =)